# Delete optimization using mysql partitioned table (MySQL 5.1)

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, database-partitioning

I have a log table that gets processed every night.  Processing will be done on data that was logged yesterday. Once the processing is complete I want to delete the data for that day.  At the same time, I have new data coming into the table for the current day.  I partitioned the table based on day of week.  My hope was that I could delete data and insert data at the same time without contention.  There could be as many as 3 million rows of data a day being processed.  I have searched for information but haven't found anything to confirm my assumption.
I don't want to have the hassles of writing a job that adds partitions and drop partitions as I have seen in other examples.  I was hoping to implement a solution using seven partions.  eg.

```
    CREATE TABLE `professional_scoring_log` (
      `professional_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `score_date` date NOT NULL,
      `scoring_category_attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `displayable_score` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`professional_id`,`score_date`,`scoring_category_attribute_id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (DAYOFWEEK(`score_date`))
    (PARTITION Sun VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION Mon VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION Tue VALUES LESS THAN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION Wed VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION Thu VALUES LESS THAN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION Fri VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
     PARTITION Sat VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

When my job that processes yesterday's data is complete, it would delete all records where score_date = current_date-1.  At any one time, I am likely only going to have data in one or two partitions, depending on time of day.

Are there any holes in my assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charlie, I don't see any holes in your logic/assumptions.

I guess my one comment would be why not use the drop/add partition syntax? It has to be more efficient than DELETE FROM .. Where ..; and it's just two calls - no big deal -- store "prototype" statements and substitute for "Sun" and "2" as required for each day of the week -- I often use sprintf for doing just that

```
ALTER TABLE `professional_scoring_log` DROP PARTITION Sun;


ALTER TABLE `professional_scoring_log` ADD PARTITION (
    PARTITION Sun VALUES LESS THAN (2)
);
```

Comment: The reason for not doing the ALTER TABLE is more about database permissions and existing processes and procedures that we have in place.  We don't grant the ability to perform DDL commands to the job user.  Granting delete permissions to a single table was more palatable than granting ALTER permissions.

Comment: Makes sense - procedural issues are as much a part of our reality as anything else -- Take care

Comment: For future reference, MySQL 5.5. introduced TRUNCATE PARTITION, eliminating the need of dropping and adding a partition. See here (scroll a bit further down): http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html